# What is the point of column families?

Tags: nosql

I've seen that NoSQL database systems like *RocksDB* offer a feature called *column families*. I believe I understand what the concept refers to, but what are the actual (practical) benefits of using them? I presume they can improve look-up performance in some cases, or space locality of key-value entires, at the very least? It wouldn't seem to affect the actual semantics of database access, however, as far as I understand. Is this correct? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've just uncovered some interesting information from the *RocksDB* [FAQ](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/RocksDB-FAQ). (RocksDB is a K-V store.)

Here are some relevant extracts.

> Q: What are column families used for?
>
> A: The most common reasons of using column families: (1) use different
>   compaction setting, comparators, compression types, merge operators,
>   or compaction filters in different parts of data; (2) drop a column
>   family to delete its data; (3) one column family to store metadata and
>   another one to store the data.
>
> Q: What's the difference between storing data in multiple column
>   family and in multiple rocksdb database?
>
> A: The main differences will be backup, atomic writes and performance
>   of writes. The advantage of using multiple databases: database is the
>   unit of backup or checkpoint. It's easier to copy a database to
>   another host than a column family. Advantages of using multiple column
>   families: (1) write batches are atomic across multiple column families
>   on one database. You can't achieve this using multiple RocksDB
>   databases. (2) If you issue sync writes to WAL, too many databases may
>   hurt the performance.
>
> Q: I have different key spaces. Should I separate them by prefixes, or
>   use different column families?
>
> A: If each key space is reasonably large, it's a good idea to put them
>   in different column families. If it can be small, then you should
>   consider to pack multiple key spaces into one column family, to avoid
>   the trouble of maintaining too many column families.

Answer (score 3):

I know you're not looking for a parallel with SQL but this article explains plan simply the purpose and practical benefit of Column Families.

From [Understanding the Cassandra Data Model from a SQL Perspective](http://www.rubyscale.com/post/143067472270/understanding-the-cassandra-data-model-from-a-sql) on RubyScale:

> What is a Column Family for then? Just a table prefix? A Column Family
>   has a number of settings that go with it that alter it’s behavior.
>   **There are cache settings for the keys (the UUIDs in this example),
>   cache settings for the entire rows (the entire table in this example),
>   and most importantly, sorting. In Cassandra there is no OFFSET, only
>   LIMIT and the equivalent of BETWEEN**. In this example, the column names
>   are just strings but they could also be integers or timestamps and
>   they are always stored in sort order. One Column Family might have
>   timestamp-sorted data where you query things by time slice and another
>   might be address book data where you query things in alphabetical
>   order. The only sorting you get to do after the fact is reversing a
>   particular slice.

Comment: Interesting. As you say, it doesn't fully answer the question, but it does provide a hint. Thanks.